# No updates found after apt-get update

Tags: 11.04, apt

I think I have a problem. I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and I don't receive any new updates since 19 November when I done autoremove command. I don't believe that there are no updates.

Comment: @Aditya Related, but not a duplicate, since [*new* updates really aren't available](http://askubuntu.com/a/230202/22949).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade: support for Ubuntu 11.04 officially ended on 28 October 2012, so it's not actually supported anymore. I'm not really sure why you don't believe there are no updates.

Comment: Hmm, 28 october you said. Ok, time to upgrade. Thanks